# Error while building project : resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am getting this error

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  error: resource style/CardView (aka [packagename].qa:style/CardView) not found
error: style attribute 'attr/cardElevation (aka (packagename).qa:attr/cardElevation)' not found.
```

error shows here

```
</style>
    <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/mtrl_card_elevation</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?attr/colorBackgroundFloating</item>
  </style>
```

I tried `clean`, `invalid cache and restart`, updated the android studio, still error is showing up

Comment: check this dependency in ur build.gradle 'implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-vxxx' if not include it then rebuilt

Comment: it is there and it was working fine earlier

Answer (score 0):

check the wanted dimens if exist, or the style you wanna get by using "?attr"